# Can a Symbol in ruby create a Column in db table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

I have a person table with name and email as the columns,

Will the following line create a column "address" in the table:

```
person = Person.create(:name => "August", :email => "august@gmail.com", :address => "Maker Street")
```

Comment: Did you try running that command in console?

Comment: No! You need to add `address` column with the **migration**.

Comment: @Pavan: in some databases, it _will_ create the field :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Will be glad to know which databases :)

Comment: @Pavan mongodb, for example :)

Comment: Thanks shivam, Pavan, SergioTulentsev for your replies. I haven't added the column with migration. For a similar scenario, I get a warning saying - **WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: number**

Answer (score 2):

Do following steps -

step 1 : First Create new column Address in Person table, by following command -

```
rails g migration add_address_to_person address:string
```

step 2 : Migrate database

```
rake db:migrate
```

step 3 : Create Person with Address column -

```
person = Person.create(:name => "August", :email => "august@gmail.com", :address => "Maker Street")
```

Above method will insert values in Person table's Name, Email and Address column.

Comment: Generator won’t run a migration. `rake db:migrate` or like is needed in between.

Comment: Thanks AmitSuroliya and mudasobwa for your answer!

Comment: But Amit,for a similar scenario, I get a warning saying - WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: number. Do you have any idea why I get error of undefined method when updating address for above asked scenario and warning for the other?

Comment: @August.........You need to permit `number` in `params`, like params.require(:person).permit(:number, :name,:email,:address)

Comment: Thanks, in the other scenario there are ten columns from terms_1, .. , terms_10 in database. So while updating one of the records the code tries to update for terms_12, which is not possible and gives error for one user and warning with no update for other users.. Do you have any idea why this might happening?

Comment: here the number with terms_# is fetched from another table. and used symbols like `:"terms_#"`, `.send` method the column is updated

Comment: Is terms_12 in database column of table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81485/discussion-between-august-and-amit-suroliya).

Answer (score 2):

Add a new column `address` to the `Person` table:

```
rails g migration AddAddressToPerson address:string
```

Migrate the database:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Create the record:

```
person = Person.create(:name => "August", :email => "august@gmail.com", :address => "Maker Street")
```

---

**Note**: You could also use `rails g migration AddAddressToPerson address` since `string` is the default datatype.

Comment: Thanks @rahulv. I haven't added the column with migration. For a similar scenario, I get a warning saying - WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: number

Comment: What is the similar scenario?

Comment: The similar scenario is that I'm trying to update a column which doesn't exists in database.

Comment: It's not possible! Why do you need that?